# Proving a theorem in Ergodicity

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning, ergodic-theory

I read the theorem stated below on Wikipedia
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Formal_definition). But I do not understand how to prove the equivalence of these different definitions.Any hints are welcome. Thanks.

while trying to prove that 1 implies 2 i am given a set $E$ whose symmetric difference with $T(E)$ is of measure zero. So i wanted to find a set $F=E \cup N$ where $N$ is a null set such that $T(F)=F$. But i am unable to find such a set. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can find this in any book on ergodic theory.

Comment: @SimingTu i have not read any book on ergodic theory i have studied only basic measure theory, so i would like to prove using the techniques i know. So could you please give some hints

Comment: Hint for the first one implies the second one: you can try to construct an invariant set from $E$. You can add some details of where you are stuck, so that I can know how to help you.

Comment: @SimingTu edited my question actually i am having trouble finding the invariant set

Comment: You can try this set: $F=\cap_{N=0}^{\infty}\cup_{n=N}^{\infty}T^{-N}E$

Comment: @SimingTu very nice set i could also get the proof that $\mu(F)=\mu(E)$ thanks a lot but now i am struck in proving 1 implies 3. please give some hints.

Comment: You can use 2 to prove 3.

Comment: @SimingTu thanks a lot for all your help i was finally able to prove it thanks a lot :)